# How to get file system meta-data in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, metadata

I'm writing a program that should output a meta-info (size, permissions to execute / read / write, time of last modification) of all files from the specified directory.

So i found class from java, named as BasicFileAttributes ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html)). 
All the arguments needed to call the method are described there. However, my IDE gives the error,

> None of the following functions can be called with arguments supplied

...highlighting with red Path. I cannot understand exactly where I made a stupid mistake. I would be very grateful for the advice

```
val path = readLine().toString()
val attr = Files.readAttributes("img.png", BasicFileAttributes.class)
```

or doesn't work either

```
val path = readLine().toString()
val attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Files.readAttributes` takes a `Path` as its first parameter, not a `String`.  Also, you need to pass a Java Class type, not a KClass type.  You want something like this:

```
val path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(readLine())
val attr = Files.readAttributes<BasicFileAttributes>(path, BasicFileAttributes::class.java)
```